# match multiple word in the list with a string

Tags: python

I want to match a multiple words in the list with input string and return a list of matched words. 
for example:

```
x = input("Enter a string?")
keywords= ["freeway", "doesn't turn on", "dropped", "got sick", "traffic jam", " car accident"]
```

output:

```
Enter a string? there is a car accident on the freeway so that why I am late for the show. 

the list of matched words are: car accident, freeway
```

I researched and some people suggest to use any():
if any(keyword in x for keyword in keywords) but it only return true or false. 
how can I return a list of matched words. Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tride and true [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library.

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_matches(s, keys, include_duplicates=False):
    pattern = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, keys)))
    all_matches = pattern.findall(s, re.IGNORECASE)

    if not include_duplicates:
        all_matches = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(all_matches).keys())
    return all_matches
```

This is very versitile in that there's no needing to worry about retrieving matches out of order *(thanks to `dict.fromkeys`)*. And you have the option to include duplicates in the response.

---

## Explanation

All I am doing with re is creating a pattern looking for every string in `keywords` *(`keys)* seperated by a`|`this tells`re` to look for all matches of keys.

[re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns matches in order as explained in the docs:

> Return **all non-overlapping matches** of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are **returned
>   in the order found.**

This does not take into account duplicates, so the `include_duplicates` argument is included for such cases where you want them. You could just turn the results into a set to remove duplicates, although you would lose order integrity, thus I used [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) and turned that back into a list.

---

## Put into use:

```
text = "there is a car accident on the freeway so that why I am late for the show."
keywords= {
  "freeway",
  "doesn't turn on",
  "dropped",
  "got sick",
  "traffic jam",
  " car accident"}
matches = get_matches(text, keywords)
print(f"the list of matched words are: {', '.join(matches)}")
#the list of matched words are:  car accident, freeway, freeway
```

You can try this out for yourself https://repl.it/repls/AbleEssentialDribbleware.

**Edit**

*As you asked in your comment:*

To explain that this line does:

```
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, keys)))
```

- `re.compile` - Makes a regex pattern from a string. - [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)
- `join` Takes an iterable of strings and makes one string of them all separated by the string preceding string. - [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- `map` & `re.escape` *you could take this out for your case* **but**should you, or anyone reading this, be using using more complex keyword searches, this takes each keyword and escapes `re`'s special metacharacters - (see the docs: [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape))

This line could be rewritten without `map` and `re.escape` and still work fine like this:

```
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(keys))
```

Just know you cannot include characters like: `(` or `*` etc... in your keywords.

Comment: Can you explain to me this line of code: re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, keys)

Comment: What part? I added an explanation to the end of my answer.

Comment: If this answer helped you please accept it as an answer using the check mark to the left of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585460/225020).

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in keywords if i in x]
```

edit: this does what you want it to

Comment: It's recommended that you add some explanation to what your code is supposed to do, as it will make your post more helpful to the OP and other users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets to find out which strings match between user entered strings and your keywords.

Check the below code:

```
keywords= ["freeway", "doesn't turn on", "dropped", "got sick", "traffic jam", " car accident"]

user_strings = []

while True:
    x = input("Enter a string?")
    if x == 'exit':
        break
    user_strings.append(x)

print ("User strings = %s" %(user_strings))
print ("keywords = %s" %(keywords))

print ("Matched Words = %s" %(list(set(keywords) & set(user_strings))))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a string?"doesn't turn on"
Enter a string?"freeway"
Enter a string?"Hello"
Enter a string?"World"
Enter a string?"exit"
User strings = ["doesn't turn on", 'freeway', 'Hello', 'World']
keywords = ['freeway', "doesn't turn on", 'dropped', 'got sick', 'traffic jam', ' car accident']
Matched Words = ['freeway', "doesn't turn on"]
```

Comment: thank you for your help but it only works if I input specific keyword. it doesn't work if I input a long string.